# VSTO-Excel Custom Task Pane AutoResize based on Screen Resolution

Tags: excel, vsto, customtaskpane

I have a problem with my VSTO addin for excel. 
I tried creating custom task pane fot my addin. However, when I tried to deploy it on a screen with different resolution from the developer's monitor, the addin does not automatically fits the screen. Note: my clients have different screen resolution.

On my vsto project, i tried to create a custom user control, and attach it on the excel pane.

Please see my code below:

```
        private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        taskPaneView = new ucCusipAddPanel();

        if (myTaskPane == null)
        {
            myTaskPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(taskPaneView, "My Custom Task Pane");
            myTaskPane.DockPosition = Office.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionRight;
            myTaskPane.DockPositionRestrict = Office.MsoCTPDockPositionRestrict.msoCTPDockPositionRestrictNoChange;
            myTaskPane.Visible = true;
            myTaskPane.Width = 303;
        }
        else
        {
            myTaskPane.Visible = true;
            taskPaneView.BringToFront();
            taskPaneView.Focus();
        }
    }
```

**ucCusipAddPanel** is the name of my user control.

This is how invoke my custom taskpane upon ribbon button click. I already set the ***AutoSize*** property to true of my user control however still the problem exists.

How could I resolve this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to play with the `AutoScaleMode`  of the `myTaskPane` object.

I think the correct solution is to use:   `myTaskPane.AutoScaleMode = AutoScaleMode.Dpi;`

see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.forms.autoscalemode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Hi. I tried to invoke the AutoScaleMode property of myTaskPane object, however, that property is not available for that object. How can I set it? Thank you.

Comment: Sorry it should be set to your taskPaneView

Comment: Thanks, I already tried it before hand and still the problem exists. :(

Comment: did you set it before to the Add() method ? if not it should be the case

Comment: also try with AutoScaleMode.Font;

Comment: I tried the AutoScaleMode.DPI and AutoScaleMode.Font and it seems that both partially worked. Thanks to that! :)

Comment: But furhermore, how about when the excel instance was resized?

Comment: Please see the images here: http://imgur.com/a/LoQ8K I uploaded the sample screenshots and the RES1 and RES2 images are fine with me, but for the PROBLEM2 image (http://imgur.com/BGe3XC0), how can I resolve it? Thank you so much,

Comment: use taskPaneView.AutoScroll = true for that case , you can also directly change all those settings in the designer

Comment: Thank you I'll try this. :0